# Counting frequencies of categorical parameters, total and by groups, and appending the output to existing matrices

Tags: r, matrix, frequency, categorical-data

In my data (DPUT below) I have many categorical binary parameters holding various information about scientific papers. These are all 0=absent/no or 1=present/yes. Does the study have government funding, yes or no? Is harvest discussed in the paper, yes or no? And so on, for more than 30 parameters. I also have the nationality of the lead author. One thing I am trying to do is to have a look at the total fraction of studies being funded from governments (GVT), and the same fraction per country.

This code gives a matrix on the number of studies not funded by GVT, and those funded by GVT:

```
gvt_funding=aggregate(data.frame(count=sysrevt$GVT),list(value=sysrevt$GVT),length)
```

which gives the matrix:

```
value  count
   0      32
   1      66
```

Then I calculate the percentage of total:

```
gvt.not=format(round(((gvt_funding[1,2]/(gvt_funding[1,2]+
                       gvt_funding[2,2]))*100),1),nsmall=1)
gvt.yes=format(round(((gvt_funding[2,2]/(gvt_funding[1,2]+
                       gvt_funding[2,2]))*100),1),nsmall=1)
```

Now I want to append these percentages in a new column in the matrix, change the name of these two columns to "TOTAL"and "TOTAL%", and then to calculate the same ratios and percentages for all nations (as shown by the column "LEAD"), and append these ratios and percentages to the same matrix with matching column titles.

It is quite possible that there are several more elegant ways to do this, but this is as far as I have come...

Here's the data:

```
structure(list(YR = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013), NRAUTH = c(6, 7, 3, 22, 10, 4, 23, 4, 4, 11, 
9, 6, 7, 9, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 4, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 7, 4, 26, 6, 
2, 4, 6, 5, 7, 5, 7, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 3), LEAD = structure(c(12L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 
12L, 11L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AUS", 
"CAN", "COS", "DEU", "DNK", "GBR", "GRL", "KOR", "NOR", "POL", 
"RUS", "USA"), class = "factor"), CAN = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), DNK = c(0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GRL = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), USA = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0), NOR = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RUS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), NATX = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ALL = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), AB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), DS = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), EG = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), GB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), KB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), KS = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), LS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), MC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), NB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), NW = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), SB = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0), SH = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), VM = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), WH = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), GVT = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1
), NGO = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), COM = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ACA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FUNDX = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), FUNDNN = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
), POPSTAT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POPABU = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POPTR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BOUND = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), HARV = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), CC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), HAB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), HABP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POLL = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
), SHIP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TOUR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BEH = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), REPEC = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ZOO = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), PHYS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TEK = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), HWC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PRED = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), METH = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), DIS = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ANA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), POPGEN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), EVO = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RESIMP = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), ISSUE = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PROT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PEFF = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("YR", 
"NRAUTH", "LEAD", "CAN", "DNK", "GRL", "USA", "NOR", "RUS", "NATX", 
"ALL", "AB", "BB", "BS", "CS", "DS", "EG", "FB", "GB", "KB", 
"KS", "LS", "LP", "MC", "NB", "NW", "SB", "SH", "VM", "WH", "GVT", 
"NGO", "COM", "ACA", "FUNDX", "FUNDNN", "POPSTAT", "POPABU", 
"POPTR", "BOUND", "HARV", "CC", "HAB", "HABP", "POLL", "SHIP", 
"TOUR", "BEH", "REPEC", "ZOO", "PHYS", "TEK", "HWC", "PRED", 
"METH", "DIS", "ANA", "POPGEN", "EVO", "RESIMP", "ISSUE", "PROT", 
"PA", "PEFF"), row.names = c(NA, -43L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
tab <- addmargins(table(sysrevt$LEAD, sysrevt$GVT), 1)
tab <- cbind(tab, 100 * prop.table(tab, 1))
colnames(tab) <- c('gvt.not', 'gvt.yes', 'gvt.not(%)', 'gvt.yes(%)')
rownames(tab)[nrow(tab)] <- 'TOTAL'
round(tab, 2)
```

The output is

```
      gvt.not gvt.yes gvt.not(%) gvt.yes(%)
AUS         1       1      50.00      50.00
CAN         1       8      11.11      88.89
COS         1       0     100.00       0.00
DEU         1       3      25.00      75.00
DNK         0       4       0.00     100.00
GBR         1       0     100.00       0.00
GRL         0       1       0.00     100.00
KOR         1       0     100.00       0.00
NOR         0       1       0.00     100.00
POL         1       0     100.00       0.00
RUS         1       1      50.00      50.00
USA         7       9      43.75      56.25
TOTAL      15      28      34.88      65.12
```

Comment: Yes! Then, finally I need to do the same for each of the five nations CAN, DNK,NOR,RUS and USA, all output in the same matrix, with YEAR in the first column.